# Material removal in a geometric shape

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, geometric-transform

I want to do the same as in this program but drilling the rectangle in another direction, along an axis other than that of the cylinder :

```
plot = Disk[{0, 0}, 3]
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics@plot;
reg = RegionProduct[mesh, Line[{{0}, {N[6]}}]];

plot2 = Rectangle[{-1, -2}]
mesh2 = DiscretizeGraphics@plot2;
reg2 = RegionProduct[mesh2, Line[{{3}, {N[8]}}]];

rd = RegionDifference[reg, reg2];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Lighter[RGBColor["#2980b9"]], rd}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True]
```

**How to do ?**

Comment: Do you want to `Rotate` reg2?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. Also, do not forget to upvote the answer(s) you like and accept the most suitable answer by clicking on the checkmark right next to that answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the piece to subtract in an arbitrary direction, e.g.:

```
plot2 = Rectangle[{-1, -2}]
mesh2 = DiscretizeGraphics@plot2;
```

Then you can rotate and translate the object as needed by defining a transformation function "transform" and transfrom the object accordingly:

```
transform =  Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, 0, 2}], RotationTransform[  Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}]];
reg2 = GeometricTransformation[ RegionProduct[mesh2, Line[{{-8}, {8.}}]], transform ];
```

Then we can create the subtraction and plot the result:

```
rd = RegionDifference[reg, reg2];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Lighter[RGBColor["#2980b9"]], rd}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also experiment with `CSGRegion`

```
CSGRegion["Difference",
 {Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 6}}, 2],
  Cuboid[{-1, -1, 2}, {-2, -2, 3}]},
 Axes -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```